# Windows 8.1 Dynamic ListView's Observable Collection

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-8.1

Right now I have a simple example where I have two hard coded list views.

List View 1 is attached to Item Source Observable Collection List 1.

List View 2 is attached to Item Source Observable Collection List 2.

These lists are two static lists I have defined. I have drag enabled on List 1 and Drop enabled on List 2. On the drop event handler I removed from Collection 1 and Add the item to collection 2. This all works great.

Now I want to introduce List Views created on the fly programmatically. What would be the best way to handle being able to drag and drop between them? I will still have List 1 which will be fed initially by my Observable Collection. Should I just be adding/removing from the list views Item Collection or should I try and let an observable handle that?

You can grab the current code spike here (VS2013 Windows 8.1):

http://andrewherrick.com/spike/listviewdragdrop.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using a static Dictionary of ObservableCollections that I add/remove from on the fly.